# Reply to chat messages on mobile

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web

Is there a way to reply to chat messages from the mobile chat site? I have only been able to manually @ ping people, but that doesn't link conversations together.

Comment: ...and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126874/missing-features-of-mobile-chat

Comment: ...and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175832/add-functionality-to-mobile-chat

Comment: So, as you figured out - mobile chat is virtually useless.