# Allow me to flag messages from mobile chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web, chat-flags

I like using my mobile to chat, even though I can't use some cool features in the mobile version. But please add a button and allow me to flag chat messages, when there is an urgent need.

A few hours ago, I faced a situation in chat, and SE crew promptly acted to the flags raised by others, but I couldn't raise a flag due to this limitation. Please add a flag button for mobile users too.

Comment: Agreed, worth to mention it's part of a [bigger feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175832/add-functionality-to-mobile-chat).

Comment: It's more of a work-around than the solution, but requesting the desktop version helps, if only troublesome.